# Filter a table based on only particular filed in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am doing a search in my table content, at a particular time I want to filter my table only based on the particular field.

For example, I have a table with number, name and content column. When I enter text in the search box it should search the matched value only in number and name, not the content. How to do this in angular js.

Answer (score 1):

You can supply a filter function to your ng-repeat assuming your code is structured like the following,

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </th>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items | filter : ctrl.filterOnNameAndNumber">
            <td>{{item.number}}</td>
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.content}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

ctrl.filterOnNameAndNumber = function (item) {
    // filter logic here
    return item.name.indexOf(ctrl.search) > -1 || item.number === ctrl.search;
}
```

Fore more information, read the following API docs,

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 0):

You can try 
[ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/)
instead **table**.